# How to get a point value from a noise texture

Tags: shader-nodes

I wish to make a specific object be fully one color decided by its position in a noise map, so that moving it in 3d space changes its color in full.[image: Picture shows objects in space and there location on a the noise map, not no fading on the edges of any of them fomr nearby colors]

Answer (score 3):

If you're not deforming it, use object info/location as the vector to the noise texture:

[image]